# .net core - MVC - Using an IEnumerable on a Viewmodel returns empty model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im populating a collapsable accordion from bootstrap, and there is a table in each and one of the collapsable blocks. In the GET request I get all viewmodels related to the customer and then I group them by month which makes the List an IEnumerable> that I send to the view and loop so that each accordion block is "Januari" and its table with data, and so on..

So, to summarize the view: I loop the groups in Model, add The date for each group in the accordion "Keys" to make the accordion blocks unique and then i add a table in the accordion block with all the rows in the group. Every row in the table have only one input, its a checkbox.

**Problem:** When I submit I get nothing. Empty list... This is the GET/POST and the View.

Actions..

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CheckOffPriceListsAdjustments(int projectId)
    {
        //Get all the  priceListsAdjustments that are unchecked
        var priceListsAdjustments = _priceListsAdjustmentsHandler.GetPriceListsAdjustmentsByProjectId(projectId)
            .Where(x => x.Checked.Equals(false)).ToList();

        if (priceListsAdjustments.Any())
        {
            // Transform them to checkOffViewModels.
            var checkOffViewModels = _customerHandler.GetPriceListsAdjustmentsForCheckOff(priceListsAdjustments);
            var proj = _projectService.GetProjectById(projectId).ProjectName;

            ViewBag.ProjectName = proj.Contains(";") ? proj.Substring(proj.IndexOf(';') + 1) : proj;

            var grouped = checkOffViewModels.GroupBy(x => x.Date).Select(grp => grp.ToList());

            return View(grouped);
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CheckOffPriceListsAdjustments(IEnumerable<List<CheckOffViewModel>> grouped)
    {
        // TODO : Update rows in DB, save changes.
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```html
@model IEnumerable<List<Blabla.Models.ViewModels.CheckOffViewModel>>
@using Blabla.Extensions


<h2>@ViewBag.ProjectName</h2>
<p id="checkOff-paragraph">blalblalblalblala....</p>

<div id="accordion">
    <form asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="CheckOffPriceListsAdjustments" method="post">
        @foreach (var group in Model)
        {
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading@(group.Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())" style="background-color: #337ab7">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <span style="color:white" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse@(group.Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                            @group.Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                        </span>
                    </h5>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse@(group.Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading@(group.Select(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="infoTable" class="table table-fixed table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Bockad</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Månad</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Kund</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Projektnr</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Projektnamn</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Uppgift</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Avdelning</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Name</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Antal tim</th>
                                    <th class="col-xs-3">Pris</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var row in group.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerName))
                                {
                                    <tr class="clickableRow">
                                        <td class="col-xs-3"><input asp-for="@row.Checked" type="checkbox" /></td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.Date</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.CustomerName</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.ProjNr</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.ProjName.TruncateString()</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.Description</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.SecCost</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.Employee</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.Hours</td>
                                        <td class="col-xs-3">@row.Price</td>
                                        <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="@row.Checked" /></td>
                                        <td><input type="hidden" asp-for="@row.PriceListsAdjustmentsId" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20px">
            <input id="checkOffPricelists-form-btn" type="submit" value="save blabla.." class="btn btn-success" style="width:25%" disabled />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So in short Model Binding isn't happening?

Comment: I think you need to give name attributes to HTML controls which maps to  the property names in the Model for model binding to happen automatically

Comment: Precisely, its not binding.. How do you mean when you say "HTML controls" ?

Comment: Post your *code*, not images of your code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, There you go, sorry about that..

Comment: @teachMe - For model binding you need to use a for loop and reference the model items by index. You then need a valid control such as TextBoxFor which  binds upon posting.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - Sorry... wrong name there! That was for the OP :)

Comment: @Wheels73, this made it work, thank you. Plz make a post containing your comment and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @teachMe - oh right..ok.. glad you got it sorted. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you need to iterate through model collections with a for loop and reference the items via an index. You will also need to use a control such as TextboxFor for the binding to work.

You can see the difference in the html generated in the source between the two.

Thanks